# Open activity from Menu item

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I'm trying to use Intent, but it does not work in Navigation Drawer. It worked only on the native Menuitem (3 points), but I want to use it in Navigation Drawer.

can anybody help me?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_one) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_two)  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you giving the id's reference correct ? Because this is the method to use intent on navigation drawer. Therefore , please check the id og navigation drawer menus

Comment: @AndroidGeek Yes, in Android studio has no errors, and it generates the apk normally. But in the app does not work.

Comment: Post your full activity code. Is your onNavigationItemSelected is called ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using **`this`** keyword , use `getApplicationContext()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.class, Activity2.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this

```
public class SetNavigationView {
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
    private Context mcontext;
-----------------------------
-----------------------------
     public SetNavigationView(final Activity activity, final NavigationView navigationView, final DrawerLayout drawer) {
     this.mcontext = activity.getApplicationContext();
    -----------------------------
    -----------------------------
      /*TODO add menu item selection */
            NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener item_click_listener = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) { 
                     if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                        // Handle the home action
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, Home.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    } 
                    -----------------------------
                    -----------------------------
                    }
    }
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item_click_listener);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This try code.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_one) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity1.class));
       //MainActivity: Active activity
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_two)  {
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class));
       //MainActivity: Active activity
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```